# "We need a computer whizz"

Tags: plot-explanation, logan-lucky

When the Logan brothers first meet Fish and Sam in order to recruit them to the gang the Logans say "We need a computer whizz".  It's even in the trailer:

But I don't remember computers being involved in any part of the scheme - so why did the Logans say this?

Comment: Umm... "Wiz" is short for "wizard". A "whizz" is a very different thing.

Comment: @ToddWilcox nope - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whizz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They needed someone to disable the credit card machines in the NASCAR track. This required someone who had a thorough knowledge of networking, computers and bank systems.

Their solution wasn't something as sophisticated as a *hack* or something. They just blew up the server/communications hub that connected the banking services to the actual banks, but it worked like a charm.